# Is there tokenauthentication in the meanjs solution?

Tags: angularjs, express, mean-stack, jwt

I am getting my head around meanjs and trying to find token authentication in https://github.com/meanjs/mean but could not find it. Are there any alternative samples that have a meanjs app implemented with JWT authentication?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/angular-fullstack/generator-angular-fullstack is a great MEAN stack template that uses JWT. It comes with authentication boilerplates, including social media oAuth logins.